# Добавить класс active

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется опросник, где каждый блок вопроса имеет класс (`.wp-polls`). Внутри блока с вопросом есть кнопка с классом (`.Buttons`). Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в первом блоке, у этого блока класс `active` убирался, а следующему блоку с классом `.wp-polls` присваивался. Блоков с вопросами может быть сколько угодно. Подскажите, каким образом можно это реализовать. Пробовал задавать массив

```
var mass = [];
$('.wp-polls').each(function(index) {
  mass.push($(this));
});
```

а потом цикл

```
for (var i = 0; i <= mass.lenght - 1; i++) {
  $('.Buttons').click(function(){
    if ($('.wp-polls').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.wp-polls').removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('wp-polls').addClass('active');
    }
  });
};
```

но цикл выдает `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто при клике на кнопку ищите его родительский элемент с классом `.wp-polls` с помощью [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). После проверяйте, если он имеет `.active`, то удаляйте этот класс и добавляйте на следующий с помощью [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  let wpPolls = $(this).closest('.wp-polls');
  if (wpPolls.hasClass('active')) {
    wpPolls.removeClass('active');
    wpPolls.next().addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.wp-polls {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wp-polls active">
  <button class="button">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="wp-polls">
  <button class="button">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="wp-polls">
  <button class="button">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="wp-polls">
  <button class="button">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="wp-polls">
  <button class="button">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="wp-polls">
  <button class="button">Next</button>
</div>
```